# Limit navigation property to parent items with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a master detail relationship where the detail record also has a link to itself in the form of parent/child (a master detail to itself).

Lets call them Order/Item/Item Child.

Each item and Item child has a foreign key reference back to the Order.

The child has a foreign key reference back to item therefore allowing item nesting or potentially rollup.

However as the children have a relationship back to the order also, whenever I use the navigation property to access the items, I also get the items.

Is there a way to limit the navigation properties within the framework such as

```
order.Items.Where(i => !i.ParentId.HasValue)
```

rather than have to do that at every point of the code where I only require the parent items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a property

```
public ICollection<Item> ItemsWithoutParent {
    get {
        return this.Items.Where(i => !i.ParentId.HasValue);
    }
}
```

and declare the Items property as private.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to do this with the edmx but this will workaround the issue.